# Why does a LocalDateTime not have a zone?

Tags: zoneddatetime, java-time

I don't understand this - a LocalDateTime by definition is in the my default time zone - correct? So why do I need to provide a zone to convert from a LocalDateTime to a ZonedDateTime?

Comment: No, your definition is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A date-time without a time-zone in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as 2007-12-03T10:15:30.`

Because it's not named particularly well. It's just a DateTime without a time-zone, and a "clock" time, as per:
`This class does not store or represent a time-zone. Instead, it is a description of the date, as used for birthdays, combined with the local time as seen on a wall clock. It cannot represent an instant on the time-line without additional information such as an offset or time-zone.`

As such, to convert to a ZonedDateTime, you need to provide context.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html